# How to slice through a python nested list (or matrix) WITHOUT using numpy or any packages

Tags: python

Suppose I have the matrix and i want the following result.

I cannot figure out how to get the resulting matrix using an efficient loop, where I take ANY given array of columnsToDelete and rowsToDelete. I have tried many different ways and the main problem I am running into is that when i use matrix.pop() the entire row or column shifts, so the matrix ends up popping out a different row or column that I wanted.

So far I am only able to succeed if there is one single value in rowsToDelete or columnsToDelete.

For example, if I am given a matrix:

```
matrix = [[1, 0, 0, 2], 
          [0, 5, 0, 1], 
          [0, 0, 3, 5]]

rowsToDelete = [1]
columnsToDelete = [0, 2]

#The result should be [[0,2],
#                      [0,5]]

rows = [row for row in matrix]
#print rows

# if there is only one row to delete this is faster
if len(rowsToDelete) <= 1:
    for i in rowsToDelete:
        matrix.pop(i)


# if there is only one column to delete this is faster
if len(columnsToDelete) <= 1:
    for row in matrix:
        for col_value in row:
            for i in columnsToDelete:
                if col_value == i:
                    row.pop(col_value)
    for i in columnsToDelete:
        row.pop(i)


#answer should be [[0, 2],
#                 [0, 5]]
```

It is easy to do if I am just given that one situation, but the solution should take in ANY array of columnsToDelete = [ints] and ANY array of rowsToDelete=[ints] and remove those columns and rows.

Comment: Before you do anything, sort your rows/columns to delete into reverse order (or, process them in reverse order). If you need to delete rows [1,2], when you delete row 1, row 2 *becomes* row 1, so you'd have to delete [1, 2-1] instead. If you do them in reverse, you can delete row 2, row 1 doesn't change, then delete row 1.

Comment: Or better still, don't mutate any object that you are iterating over.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell us the problem you *actually* care about.

It sounds like your requirements are to

1. rapidly delete a row or column
2. without support from a C library such as numpy

The example `matrix` you offered was small. I will assume you're really manipulating something with much more than a thousand rows and columns. I will assume you're doing this repeatedly, though your question was a bit vague on what you *really* care about.

Using a C library, e.g. numpy, would be fast as it eliminates interpreter overhead, but you've ruled that out.

Consider incurring this overhead, to go from matrix to dict:

```
d = {}
for r, row in enumerate(matrix):
    for c, val in row:
        d[(r, c)] = val
```

Then you can iterate through row or column indices to `del d[(r, c)]` as desired. And incur the added overhead of converting dict back to matrix if needed.

EDIT: Here is the trivial "output a copy of the array, with rows and columns elided" copying approach I described.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3


def delete_r_c(matrix, omit_rows, omit_cols):
    omit_rows = set(omit_rows)  # a list doesn't offer O(1) lookups
    omit_cols = set(omit_cols)
    ret = []
    for r, row in enumerate(matrix):
        if r not in omit_rows:
            ret.append([val
                        for c, val in enumerate(row)
                        if c not in omit_cols])
    return ret


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(delete_r_c(
        [[1, 0, 0, 2],
         [0, 5, 0, 1],
         [0, 0, 3, 5]],
        omit_rows={1},
        omit_cols={0, 2}))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response - however this is not the solution I am looking for. I was given this problem in a coding interview. The reason this isn't the solution is because the code should take any input (input being rowsToDelete = [some list of ints] and columnsToDelete = [some list of ints]. There should be some sort of loop that parses through each array columnsToDelete and rowsToDelete and removes those columns and rows while returning the rest of the matrix.

Comment: Oh. Well then just output a copy of the array, with rows and columns elided. The `[some list of ints]` is not suitable - you want a `set()` instead. Within the `r`, `c` inner loop, just test `if c in omit_cols: continue` and `if r in omit_rows: continue`, and then emit the value if it survived both those filters.

Comment: If you can supply the code to take any array columnsToDelete = [ints] and rowsToDelete = [ints], and delete the rows from the nested array (list of lists or matrix), please supply it because I am still stuck. For example, if i have the matrix matrix = [[1, 0, 0, 2], 
          [0, 5, 0, 1], 
          [0, 0, 3, 5]],

and columnsToDelete = [0,2], rowsToDelete = [1],

I want the returned answer to be [[0, 2],
                                                     [0, 5]]